# Error while Importing Material Modules as a separate Module

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am getting below error :

```
Error in /turbo_modules/@angular/material@11.2.5/bundles/material-table.umd.js (32:19)
Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null
```

I checked many blogs that says it due to "circularly importing classes". But I am not able to figure out which class I am importing circularly.

Also this is happening only in v11 of Angular.

Below is the stackbliz reproduction :
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-iustv6?file=src/app/app.module.ts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using older `@angular/cdk` library, that seems to be an issue. Please update `@angular/cdk`, then it should work.

**From**

```
"@angular/cdk": "^7.0.0",
```

**To**

```
"@angular/cdk": "^11.2.5",
```

[**Working Stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-j5q81a?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmaterial-module.ts)

Comment: Thanks this worked. But after adding "BrowserAnimationsModule" the datatime picker is behaving weirdly. Is it still the issue of the version of the 3rd party datetime module I am using ? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ijpqj9?file=src/app/app.module.ts

Comment: This is how it behaves in Angular v8 : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xtsrs1-dynbhh?file=app/input-clearable-example.ts